# What is ungrammatical about these sentences?

Tags: grammaire

Marie    n’est pas le   comédien              que son père             était.
Mary.FEM   is      not  the comedian.MASC that  her father.MASC was

*Marie           n’est pas  la  comédienne      que son père               était.
Mary.FEM   is      not  the comedian.FEM that her father.MASC  was

FEM = feminine gender
MASC = masculine gender

(Both sentences are impossible. The intended reading is ‘Mary isn’t the comedian that her father was.’)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that ***comédien(ne)*** needs to be both masculine to agree with father and feminine to agree with Marie, but it can't.

You can pick a close *[épicène](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicenity)* word to overcome this issue:

> Marie n'est pas l'**artiste** que son père était.

Or rephrase for example that way:

> Marie n'a pas **les talents de comédien** de son père.

The controversial *écriture inclusive* would suggest this sentence but it is quite difficult to pronounce:

> Marie n'est pas **la·le comédien·ne** que son père était.

Answer (score 0):

That is a problem of languages that use two terms for functions and professions as taken up by human beings,  a masculine term and  a feminine one, without any difference in meaning. Either there is in that language a third term, which has to be of mixed gender (again without any difference in meaning), and then there are no such problems as in that impossible situation you noticed, or otherwise problems crop up.

As there is no mixed gender in French there are problems. The plural of such masculine words does take on a mixed gender nature, although this is not explicitly mentioned (The French might say for the time being that "masculine prevails", which is no precise reference to a mixed gender).

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langage_%C3%A9pic%C3%A8ne#Interpr%C3%A9tation_sp%C3%A9cifique_des_masculins_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9riques))
>
> **Interprétation spécifique des masculins génériques**
>
> À partir des années 1970, certaines études montrent que le sens spécifique du masculin est pratiquement impossible à inhiber. Ces résultats sont corroborés par des études plus récentes. On peut citer une étude menée en 2013 par Sato et al, sur la façon dont les locuteurs francophones et les locuteurs anglophones interprètent les référents pour des noms de métier au pluriel (par exemple, « les assistants sociaux » et l’équivalent anglais the social workers). Le français et l’anglais diffèrent dans leur système linguistique de genre : le français est une langue à « genre grammatical », qui utilise les masculins de façon générique pour renvoyer notamment à des groupes mixtes (cf. la règle « le masculin l’emporte »), alors que l’anglais est une langue à « genre naturel », qui n’associe pas de genre grammatical à ses noms et utilise des formes épicènes pour renvoyer à des groupes mixtes.

---

- Marie n’est pas le comédien que son père était. Marie n’est pas la comédienne que son père était.

This has to be formulated differently; here are three ways, in particular that one making use of the plural, but there are more.

- En tant que comédienne Marie n'est pas ce qu'en tant que comédien était son père.
- L'art de la comédie de Marie n'est pas celui de son père.
- En tant que comédiens Marie et son père ne se ressemblent pas.